# SQL Server 2012 Win32 Share Permissions with EFS and FileTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, filestream, filetable, encrypting-file-system

I've got SQL Server 2012 working with my Visual Studio SQL Project, as discussed in more detail on [my other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949739/sql-server-2012-full-text-search-on-filestreams-with-windows-encrypting-file-sys). FILESTREAMS are enabled, FileTables are created in their own FileGroup, and my SQL Project generates good indexable/searchable FILESTREAM DBs, *as long as EFS (Encrypted File System) is disabled*. When I enable EFS on the physical paths (enabled on SQL's Data directory), I cannot read or write files to the FileTable Win32 share. FWIW, I can create and delete *directories* through the share.

From what I've read on [Bruce Jackson's blog](http://blog.brucejackson.info/2013/04/sql-file-tabletechnical-details.html), it should "just work", but right now, enabling or disabling EFS is acting as a toggle: **EFS on** => drag and drop to/from the share gets permission denied; **EFS off** => drag and drop to/from the share works great.

SQL Server is running under its own local account, and I'm performing all other operations (using SSMS, Windows Explorer, etc) as my domain account, which is a local administrator and mapped to dbo in SQL Server. I'd think I should have plenty of permissions. Also, querying BLOBS through SSMS works fine. It's just the Win32/UNC share access that's broken when EFS is enabled.

Anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: Still not sure what my exact problem is, but I granted access to a different domain user to the FileTable, and they were able to read and write. So I either stumbled into an edge case or goofed something up.